# How to show items of a folder on home page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a library with a folder which has few items.
I want to display the items of this folder to be displayed on home page.

We can show all items in the library but is there any way to show items of a folder in library.

Comment: I have already checked that question but not satisfied with their approach. I wanted OOTB solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ! You can use a web part. Go to your home page and click Edit-->web part-->insert-->Apps-->select your library-->add or select which folder you want(If you have many folder in your library)

If you need show documents without folders you can switch it in "Current View" Modify this View ->Folders->Show all items without folders.

[image]

Comment: where this please "add which folder you want" ? could you add print screen !